# Blurry X11 forwarding via MobaXTerm

Tags: x11, x11-forwarding

I have established an ssh connection from Win10 to RedHat machine via MobaXTerm. I have also enabled X11 forwarding, but when I launch eclipse or gedit or anything else the application window looks blurry, i.e. not really crystal sharp as it would look be it run natively. Below is how it looks like when forwarded from a linux machine. Any clue how to make it look more sharp?

[image]

Answer (score 28):

right click mobaxterm executable or shortcut

go to compatibility tab

go to high dpi settings

check the box override dpi table

leave dropdown to application

apply

restart mobaxterm

launch the app

Answer (score 3):

I found a similar issue when working with VcXsrv and the solution for that one worked for me in MobaXTerm as well.
I'm going to guess that your screen is a high DPI one as it seems like that's where most people seem to have this issue.

Try going to the MobaXTerm executable, right-click it and go to properties.
Inside properties, click on the Compatibility tab and then mark the check to disable display scaling on high DPI.

Answer (score 3):

I have 125% display scale and the same issue. In MobaXTerm (21.4) I've changed the following setting to make applications look sharper:

`MobaXTerm / Settings / X11 / DPI: auto`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with blurry Mobaxterm windows on Win10. Try to change scale and layout of the monitor in Windows to 100% like in 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgiEg.jpg), and it worked for me.

Comment: But we are looking for a solution to make the MobaXTerm output sharp on a high DPI display so setting 100 % scaling is not a good solution.

Comment: @ondrejsv, you can read the question again and will find that there's no specification about high DPI display, as well as this solution worked perfectly in my case, so it is a good possible solution, even if not a generic one. It could help at least a part of the readers of this post.

Comment: Modifying Windows settings is not an option. Release notes of v10.5 says that it supports High DPI but only for its own UI, I guess.

https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-new-release-10.5/